# Kotlin Spring Boot: database is empty despite creating a table in schema.sql

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, kotlin, jdbc

I'm following this very simple tutorial to setup a REST API using Kotlin, Gradle and Spring Boot:
https://kotlinlang.org/docs/jvm-spring-boot-restful.html
But when I run the app (by clicking play) and visit localhost:8080 I get an error saying that the table "MESSAGES" is not found and the database is empty.
I know for sure that my application.properties is read because changing `server.port` worked,
I've tried many things like moving schema.sql directly under main/resources, adding `spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=none` in application.properties or marking the resources folder as "Source" but to no avail.

It seems my schema.sql is not being executed and I can't figure out why !

Versions: Windows 10, IntelliJ IDEA 2022.2.2, Java 17, Spring 2.7.4

[Main file gist](https://gist.github.com/Inspirateur/a8d478f04498d1b61f0b5a006b00a9da)

application.properties:

```
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=org.h2.Driver
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:file:./data/testdb
spring.datasource.username=sa
spring.datasource.password=password
spring.datasource.schema=classpath:sql/schema.sql
spring.datasource.initialization-mode=always
```

sql/schema.sql:

```sql
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS messages (
  id     VARCHAR(60)  DEFAULT RANDOM_UUID() PRIMARY KEY,
  text   VARCHAR      NOT NULL
);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved it !
This IntelliJ tutorial was written for Spring 2.6 (no longer available in Spring Initializr) and in 2.7 these 2 keys changed in application.properties:
`spring.datasource.initialization-mode` -> `spring.sql.init.mode`
`spring.datasource.schema`  -> `spring.sql.init.schema-locations`
[full list of key changes](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/wiki/Spring-Boot-2.7.0-Configuration-Changelog)

Replacing them in my application.properties worked !

New application.properties:

```
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=org.h2.Driver
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:file:./data/testdb
spring.datasource.username=sa
spring.datasource.password=password
spring.sql.init.schema-locations=classpath:sql/schema.sql
spring.sql.init.mode=always
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding these in your application.properties

```
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but it doesn't work for me :(

Comment: can you share some code

Comment: ok i'll add gists of the files